# firestore - populate select options from firestore data collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to learn how to use react with firestore.

I have 2 select options in my form, each of which is populated by different collections of records stored in firestore.

I had this working when I only used a single firestore collection, but now I'm trying to add a second, I'm running into trouble.

My form has collections named abs_for_codes and anzic_codes.

I have this function to load them:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        // const fsDB = firebase.firestore(); // Don't worry about this line if it comes from your config.
        let options = [];
        await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            options.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            options
        });

        let anzic = [];
        await fsDB.collection("anzic_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            anzic.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ANZIC ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            anzic
        });
    }
```

I can see in the console that the first collection loads entirely, and the first document from the second collection loads before this error appears:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of
>   undefined

The initial state is defined as:

```
state = {
        options: [],
        anzic: [],

    }
```

In the render method I have the consts defined as:

```
const { options } = this.state; 
const { anzic } = this.state;
```

And the form fields are:

**anz_for_codes**

```
<Select
                                                    key={`my_unique_select_keyfieldOfResearch`}
                                                    name="fieldOfResearch"
                                                    isMulti
                                                    className={
                                                        "react-select-container" +
                                                        (errors.fieldOfResearch && touched.fieldOfResearch
                                                        ? " is-invalid"
                                                        : "")
                                                    }
                                                    classNamePrefix="react-select"
                                                    value={values.fieldOfResearch}

                                                    onChange={selectedOptions => {
                                                        // Setting field value - name of the field and values chosen.
                                                        setFieldValue("fieldOfResearch", selectedOptions)}
                                                        }
                                                    onBlur={setFieldTouched}
                                                    options={options}
                                                    />    

                                                    {errors.fieldOfResearch && touched.fieldOfResearch && 
                                                    <ErrorMessage
                                                    name="fieldOfResearch"
                                                    component="div"
                                                    className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                                                />}
```

**anzic_codes**

```
<Select
                                                    key={`my_unique_select_keyindustrySector`}
                                                    name="industrySector"
                                                    isMulti
                                                    className={
                                                        "react-select-container" +
                                                        (errors.industrySector && touched.industrySector
                                                        ? " is-invalid"
                                                        : "")
                                                    }
                                                    classNamePrefix="react-select"
                                                    value={values.industrySector}

                                                    onChange={selectedOptions => {
                                                        // Setting field value - name of the field and values chosen.
                                                        setFieldValue("industrySector", selectedOptions)}
                                                        }
                                                    onBlur={setFieldTouched}
                                                    options={anzic}
                                                    />    

                                                    {errors.industrySector && touched.industrySector && 
                                                    <ErrorMessage
                                                    name="industrySector"
                                                    component="div"
                                                    className="invalid-feedback d-block"
                                                />}
```

The only place I use replace is in the component did mount function,

I don't actually know what this segment means (or how to find a reference source to figure it out):

```
replace(/( )/g, '')
```

so not sure where I'm going wrong. It works in the abs_for_codes, but seems to be incorrect in the anzic_codes. If I remove that fragment from the function, then the options array is populated with undefined as the title and then the ANZIC code (which is the correct number).

Answer (score 0):

Ah - this one is really obvious. Sorry - I hope this helps someone else. The "title" is case sensitive. My document collection names that field "Title" in in the anzic codes table. Hope this helps someone else.